# How do you switch to a different site template in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sitetemplate

If you used a site template (such as the Document Center template) and wish to use a different template (such as a Team Site), how can you accomplish this? More importantly, how do you do this without losing permissions that have been setup on the document libraries, lists, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in SP2010. Once a site is setup with a template that is how it is created. That being said, you can simply add the functionality you require to make the site appear to be of another template. By selecting a template, you are simply setting a starting point and not restricted future usage.